# CORBA over WiFi run very slow

Tags: java, wifi, corba

I have java server-client application using CORBA connection. the application running well with wired connection, but when connected via WiFi the client app running very slowly. Anybody has an idea why CORBA very slow over WiFi?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a 1Gbit wired network and a 150Mbit wifi?  There will be an 8x speed difference if you are.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't quantified at all what is slow and fast. There are a few things to look at, first the design of your IDL interfaces. Normally each invocation of an IDL operation results in a remote call which goes over the network. For example when you want to retrieve 1M values, don't perform 1M operations, but retrieve them in bigger chunks. Secondly, what is the payload of the invocation, what is the size of the data to transmit. If that is large and your wifi link is slow, than it just takes time to transmit the data, ZIOP (CORBA Compression) adds the ability to CORBA that it will compress your application data, something to look at. Last, is your network setup correctly, do all host names and ip addresses you use do work correctly, if for example in your wifi setup the DNS settings are not ok, than reverse lookups can kill performance.

Check your CORBA implementation to enable logging, see what is happening, how much data is transmitted, do you see errors, etc.

Comment: how to enable ZIOP in glassfish?

Comment: Not sure if glassfish supports ZIOP, you have to check their documentation. See https://svn.dre.vanderbilt.edu/viewvc/Middleware/trunk/TAO/tests/ZIOP/ for the TAO ZIOP test

Comment: what is the best suggestion to replace glassfish orb technology as data transfer on my application? I'm developing java server with EJB and JPA deployed on glassfish with java desktop as client. both server-client send big amount of data, mostly using arrayList an set.

Comment: Ask the glassfish people if they can add ZIOP to their ORB, shouldn't be to hard to do that

Answer (score 0):

CORBA  can be a very network intensive protocol if developers design CORBA objects like ordinary C++/Java Objects, this will cause several small interactions over the network. This makes it very susceptible to network latency. I.E. not the overall speed of the network but the time it takes to open a stream and send a single packet. Wireless networks can be very fast sending large packets once a connection is established, but, I suspect your wireless network is quite slow to route packets.

Comment: I don't agree that CORBA is a very network intensive protocol. An ORB normally only opens socket connections when it needs them and keeps them open as long as it can. Very small interactions can only happen if the user designs an IDL interface that needs a lot of interactions, independent of the protocol used, any technology will not perform if you make thousands of calls to do something simple. CORBA does have the advantage that it is a binary protocol and does support compression, a well designed CORBA system will outperform any other technology for request/reply kind of interaction.

Comment: @johnny -- while its possible to design efficient CORBA objects , most programmers just treat them like ordinary objects with lots of getters and setters etc.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this happen in a several projects, but that was more a lack of understanding of what it means to implement a distributed networked application. CORBA makes it easier to create such kind of systems, but it is definitively a holy grale that makes it super easy, it is still hard work to create this kind of systems.

Comment: -1 for CORBA "making several small interactions over the network" and for it being a "very network intensive protocol". Neither of those are true: a single CORBA request maps to a single GIOP request on the network (not multiples), and the CDR encoding is quite efficient (for one thing, it's not self-describing and packs data structures quite efficiently).

Comment: we have another server-client application using restful that send big amount of data. but its not giving any problem with the data transfer over wired or wifi.
so I don't think the wifi network is the problem.

Comment: @Brian -- given that the poster has a "rest"full application which does not have the problem, the slowness is probably caused by a CORBA object with lots of standard OO type methods which will be vulnerable to network latency.

Comment: My point is that bad performance is not a problem inherent in CORBA, but your answer makes it read as such. Any middleware approach or technology - CORBA, REST, SOAP, RPC, Protocol Buffers, whatever - can be made to run slowly if the application built using it doesn't use it correctly. It sounds like their RESTful app might be better architected, but that doesn't mean that REST is faster than CORBA either.